# Android: Getting HTTP Page and scrape it

Tags: android, http

I'm trying to connect to a webpage and get some info and images off a page and place it in a listview.
Now, I can get the Content of the whole page but how do I just get a class or Image to show?

Code I use now:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);

       HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.wallbase.cc");
       try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
            text.append(line);
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML page is valid XML (XHTML) then you can parse the content and use XPath to get just the data you want, but if it is ugly HTML you would have to fix that (expensive, meaning costs  valuable resources to do that work) or just walk the content and look for the thing you want. I had an Android app that had to parse some really bad HTML to get a specific image out and I did it by walking it char by char and looking for the image, and when found, storing the URL that I needed to get that image object and breaking from the loop.

So in your code to do that, you would use read:

```
rd.read();
```

instead of readLine and then look at each character. It takes a lot of conditions (meaning if/else etc.) and Regular Expressions to locate the content but it is possible

**Edit**

Ahh just though that I should add how to get the Image after that. So once you have the URL for the image, something like this:

```
Bitmap retImg;
...

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(imgURLStr);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(get.getParams(),
CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(get.getParams(),
SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpResponse response;
try {
  response = httpClient.execute(get);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
  throw new IOException("Invalid protocol.");
}

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
  throw new IOException("Bad response: " +
  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent(),
8 * 1024);
retImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
bis.close();
```

then the method this was from returned that image (retImg), which was cached in a db on the device and loaded in the gui (next time round it was only pulled from the cache)